# WCF REST service does not work with parameter in URI

Tags: wcf, jquery

I have a WCF REST service (.NET4).

It works fine (browser, ajax call) for calls without parameters but I cannot get it to work with parameters. Neither in the browser nor via an ajax call.

My contract:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebGet(
    ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
    UriTemplate = "knowledgefields")]
IEnumerable<cKnowledgeField> GetKnowledgeFields();

[OperationContract]
[WebGet(
    BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
    ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
    RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
    UriTemplate = "knowledgeitems?id={id}")]
IEnumerable<cKnowledgeItem> GetKnowledgeItemsByField(string id);
```

My web.config

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings/>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/>
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <standardEndpoints>
      <webHttpEndpoint>
        <standardEndpoint name="" automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="false" defaultOutgoingResponseFormat="Json"/>
      </webHttpEndpoint>
    </standardEndpoints>
    <services>
      <service name="ExpertData.expertREST" behaviorConfiguration="META">
        <endpoint address="" bindingConfiguration="webHttpBindingWithJsonP" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="ExpertData.IexpertREST"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <protocolMapping>
      <add scheme="http" binding="webHttpBinding"/>
    </protocolMapping>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="META">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <webHttp />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="webHttpBindingWithJsonP" crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true"/>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="false" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="FindAnExpertEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/ExpertData.csdl|res://*/ExpertData.ssdl|res://*/ExpertData.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=WIN8ATWORK\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=FindAnExpert;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Ajax call:

```
  function getKnowledgeItems(id) {
      return $.ajax({
          url: "http://localhost:31634/expertREST.svc/knowledgeitems",
          dataType: "jsonp"
          data: { "id" : id + "" }
      }).then( function( data, textStatus, jqXHR ) {
          amplify.publish( "knowledgeItemsdata.updated", data );
      });
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your AJAX call is passing the ID in the message body, BUT you service expects it as as part of the query string.  Change javascript to:

```
  return $.ajax({
      url: "http://localhost:31634/expertREST.svc/knowledgeitems"
           + "?id=" + id,
      dataType: "jsonp"
  }).then( function( data, textStatus, jqXHR ) {
      amplify.publish( "knowledgeItemsdata.updated", data );
  });
```

Comment: I get the following error message: 
Failed to load resource http://localhost:31634/expertREST.svc/knowledgeitems?id=4&callback=jQuery1820015665366547182202_1354792050870&_=1354792057565

Comment: It would appear that you WCF service is no longer running on port 3163 or has changed its name.  Do your calls with no parameters still work?

Comment: Yes. It does. I get [{"Id":1,"Title":"Electrical"},{"Id":2,"Title":"Piping"},{"Id":3,"Title":"Mechanical"},{"Id":4,"Title":"Software"},{"Id":5,"Title":"Milieu"}].
It does appear like you said, when I use the parameter I get page not available.

Comment: its most likely a naming/binding issue.  could u post the javascript that calls with no parameters?

Comment: I published my service locally. Now when I try http://localhost/ExperService/expertREST.svc/knowledgefields without parameters I get the same error!? Has it got something to do with localhost??
No parameters works fine:
  function getKnowledgeFieldItems() {
    return $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:31634/expertREST.svc/knowledgefields",
      dataType: "jsonp"
    }).then( function( data, textStatus, jqXHR ) {
        amplify.publish( "knowledgeFielddata.updated", data );
    });
  }

Comment: hmmm...  Could it be the port number.  In the parameter version you are using port number 31634.  However now with no parameters you are NOT specifying a port so it defaults to 80.  Note: Visual Studio by default will assign RANDOM port numbers.  You can change that behaviour by right-clicking on the project and selecting properties.

Comment: Do not think so. I've set the project URL to http://localhost/ExpertService. That's where I publish my service. Nicely in IIS. I can call the .svc but none of the methods.

Comment: But you ajax call uses port 31634! Since non of your code is working, I give up.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding. I changed the ajax calls. They now point to http://localhost/ExpertService/expertREST.svc where my service is hosted in IIS.

I experimented with my service method that gets the data and guess what, when I hardcode the data (see code) it works! When I use LINQ to query my entity it doesn't.

Comment: public IEnumerable<cKnowledgeItem> GetKnowledgeItemsByField(string id)
{
  List<cKnowledgeItem> ki = new List<cKnowledgeItem>();
  ki.Add(new cKnowledgeItem() { Id = 4 });
  ki.Add(new cKnowledgeItem() { Id = 5, Description = "", Title = "test" });
  return ki;
}
Works!

Comment: IEnumerable<cKnowledgeItem> kitems;
            FindAnExpertEntities e = new FindAnExpertEntities();
            var query = from ki in e.KnowledgeItems
                       join kif in e.KnwoledgeFieldHasKnowledgeItems on ki.Id equals kif.knowledgeItemId 
                        where kif.knowledgeFieldId == Convert.ToInt32(id)
                        select new cKnowledgeItem() { Id = ki.Id, Title = ki.Title, Description = ki.Description };
            kitems = query;
            return kitems;
Doesn't

Comment: Good luck.  You are making way too many changes after reporting an problem.  How do you expect anyone to answer a question.  I'm giving up.